# Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly on powershell 3

Tags: powershell

I have an dll(assembly) file on the network share and want to import into powershell.
I try as follow:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-Type -Path \\path\Netlogon\Industry\Startup\Startup.dll
```

and got

```
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\path\Netlogon\Industry\Startup\Startup.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Add-Type -Path \\path\Netlogon\Industry\Startup\Startup.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Powershell version is:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                  
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}                                                                                                                                                                                        
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481                                                                                                                                                                                         
PSVersion                      3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                    
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.269                                                                                                                                                                                          
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

I search in internet about it, but does not found the solution at all.
I want to set:

```
<runtime>
    <loadfromremotesources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

in the `powershell.exe.config` file, but the file does not exist in the powershell 3.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried just adding this line to config? Otherwise just map network path as a network drive and load it from there

Comment: which config file? powershell.exe.config?

Comment: yes, powershell.exe.config

Comment: The file powershell.exe.config does not exist!!

Comment: Sorry, does not work at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109884/discussion-between-andrey-marchuk-and-zero-coding).

Comment: I think i will try to copy assembly on local machine and then execute it. I will let you know. Thanks very for helping.

Comment: Try with [System.Reflection.Assembly]::UnsafeLoadFrom("<your UNC here>")

Comment: ... and make sure it's unblocked